# Multiple $unwind and $group in mongo query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

kind of struggling around with a mongodb query. My mongo database has following structure:

```
name: String
test: String
competences: [{name: String, code: String, value: Float}]
subcompetences: [{name: String, code: String, value: Float}]
```

My query looks like this:

```
async function getAggregatedDataForCompetences(filter, category) {
    return await getCollection('competences').aggregate([
    {$match: { $or: filter }},
    {$unwind:  "$competences" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        code:  { $first: "$competences.code" },
        name:  { $first: "$competences.name"},
        avgValue: { $avg: "$competences.value" },
        subcompetences:  { $first: "$subcompetences"},
        }
    },
    {$unwind:  "$subcompetences" },
    {$group: {
        _id: "$subcompetences.code",
        code:  { $first: "$subcompetences.code" },
        name:  { $first: "$subcompetences.name"},
        avgValue: { $avg: "$subcompetences.value" },
    }}
    ]).toArray();
}
```

What am I trying to do is unwind the first (competences) array for all elements, group them by and calculate the average value for each item. The same procedure is repeated for the following subcompetences array of objects. As a result I'm getting only the average values for the last subcompetences array. Do you have any idea how can I reach the following result:

```
{
   competences: [{name: String, code: String, avgValue: Float}],
   subcompetences: [{name: String, code: String, avgValue: Float}]
}
```

Comment: Why is `competencies` grouped by `$_id` but `subcompetencies` is grouped by ``$code`?    Typo?   I think you want to group by `$code` in both, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$facet` to the rescue -- the "multigroup" operator.   Given input like this:

```
var r =
[
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "name": "N1",
    "competences": [
{name: "AAA", code: "A", value: 1.1},
{name: "BBB", code: "B", value: 2.2},
{name: "CCC", code: "C", value: 3.3}
                    ],
    "subcompetences": [
{name: "DDD", code: "D", value: 4.4},
{name: "EEE", code: "E", value: 5.5},
{name: "FFF", code: "F", value: 6.6}
]
        }

,{
    "_id" : 1, "name": "N2",
    "competences": [
{name: "AAA", code: "A", value: 9.9},
{name: "BBB", code: "B", value: 8.8},
{name: "KKK", code: "K", value: 11.11}
                    ],
    "subcompetences": [
{name: "FFF", code: "F", value: 4.9},
{name: "GGG", code: "G", value: 6.7}
]
        }
 ];
```

then `$facet` will allow you to do two groups "in parallel".   Indeed, you can do two or more complete *pipelines* at the same time (some restrictions apply):

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$facet: {
  "avg_competences": [
      {$unwind: "$competences"}
      ,{$group: {_id: "$competences.code",
           name: {$first: "$competences.name"},
           count: {$sum: 1},
           avgval: {$avg: "$competences.value"},
        }}
           ]

  ,"avg_subcompetences": [
      {$unwind: "$subcompetences"}
      ,{$group: {_id: "$subcompetences.code",
           name: {$first: "$subcompetences.name"},
           count: {$sum: 1},
           avgval: {$avg: "$subcompetences.value"},
        }}
           ]
    }
}

// The output of the stage above will be a *single* doc with two fields, 
// avg_competence and avg_subcompetences.  Let's add more fields to this doc!
,{$addFields: {N: {$reduce: {
                input: {$concatArrays: ["$avg_competences","$avg_subcompetences"]},
                initialValue: 0,
                in:{$sum: [ "$$value", "$$this.count"]}
            }}
    }}


   ]);
```

to yield:

```
{
    "avg_competences" : [
        {
            "_id" : "K",
            "name" : "KKK",
            "count" : 1,
            "avgval" : 11.11
        },
        {
            "_id" : "C",
            "name" : "CCC",
            "count" : 1,
            "avgval" : 3.3
        },
        {
            "_id" : "B",
            "name" : "BBB",
            "count" : 2,
            "avgval" : 5.5
        },
        {
            "_id" : "A",
            "name" : "AAA",
            "count" : 2,
            "avgval" : 5.5
        }
    ],
    "avg_subcompetences" : [
        {
            "_id" : "G",
            "name" : "GGG",
            "count" : 1,
            "avgval" : 6.7
        },
        {
            "_id" : "F",
            "name" : "FFF",
            "count" : 2,
            "avgval" : 5.75
        },
        {
            "_id" : "E",
            "name" : "EEE",
            "count" : 1,
            "avgval" : 5.5
        },
        {
            "_id" : "D",
            "name" : "DDD",
            "count" : 1,
            "avgval" : 4.4
        }
    ],
    "N" : 11
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Since you seem to be versed in this topic,  I would like to ask you one more question. What if I want to add on object to the final result. Let's for example count the total objects of the applied filter:  count:     { $sum : 1 }, so the final object would look like this:    { general: {count: 1234},  competences: [{name: String, code: String, avgValue: Float}], subcompetences: [{name: String, code: String, avgValue: Float}] }

Comment: You mean the total count of both `avg_competences` and `avg_subcompetences` i.e. 11 in the example above?   Also:  DOn't be shy about the vote-up arrow and also making this an accepted answer.  :-)

Comment: Answer expanded to include adding a total field to the output doc.